# Subclassing Array

Tags: java, arrays, subclassing

If you're not interested in a story, skip the first 2 paragraphs.

I was talking to a friend about arrays and why they (still) crash if you try to access an object that is out of bounds in "modern" languages like Objective C (That's my main language). So we got into a debate and I said that I could write him an Array (I named it GeniusArray) that returns null and prints out an error if you try to access something out of bounds but does not crash.

After sleeping over it I realized that if you are accessing elements that are out of bounds you have some serious errors in your code and it's maybe not bad for app to crash so you get forced to fix it. :-D

But still: I'd like to prove my point and subclass an Array and override the get() method by basically adding this one if statement that every programmer writes relatively often:

```
// Pseudo code...
if (index < array.count) element= array[index];
```

I want to do it in Java and not Objective C because that's what my friend "knows" (btw, we are both students).

To cut a long story short: I tried to subclass an Array but it doesn't seem to work. I'm get ting this:

> Access restriction: The type
>   Attribute.Array is not accessible due
>   to restriction on required library:
>    /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Classes/classes.jar   GeniusArray.java

Comment: "I realized that if you are accessing elements that are out of bounds you have some serious errors in your code and it's maybe not bad for app to crash so you get forced to fix it. :-D" - this is a very correct observation. If you had a `GeniusArray` of size 0 and said `geniusArray[0].foo()`, the program would still crash but with a far less debuggable `NullPointerException` rather than the more communicative `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Returning `null` is never the way to handle a programming error - throwing is.

Comment: The real problem with C and C++, and as you say Objective C, is that they do not detect that the index is out of bounds. So rather than a guaranteed crash anything can happen. This is much worse, for example it causes all those buffer overflow security holes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Languages such as C, C++ and Objective-C do not check array bounds (and hence result in unpredictable behaviour if you try to access an array with an invalid index) for performance reasons.

Java does check array bounds on every array access and you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you use an invalid index. Some people argue that because of this built-in check arrays in Java are less efficient than in other programming languages.

Comment: I used a try/catch block to catch java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException and the application did not crash (which is what I wanted). Seems like this is a better way of doing what I did with the GeniusArray in Java. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Only *classes* can be subclassed. Array types are not classes. (From [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.3): "There are three kinds of reference types: class types, interface types, and array types.")

Comment: Oh, that's interesting! I assumed that Array is a class just like the "NSArray" class in objective C. I see that I'll have to learn a lot regarding Java.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As you've discovered you can't subclass from an array. You'll have to subclass from (say) an ArrayList and use the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) pattern to intercept the get() methods (and related).

Unfortunately you can't provide an operator overload for [] either, so you're going to be some distance from your original objective.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at this Decorator pattern.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I recall, you really can't subclass an Array in Java (it is a special type). The VM makes some assumptions about arrays that subclassing might mess up.

Normally, I would just try to stay away from arrays. Use ArrayLists instead.